# Unable to get values from input text in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new to web dev and recently I learning DOM. 
However, I have a problem that had been bugging me . 
I am trying out to make a simple sphere volume calculator where the user can get the volume of sphere by inputting the radius.

Here is the code.

HTML

```
Enter the sphere radius : <input type="number" id="radius"> 
<button id=>Calculate !</button>
<p>Therefore, the volume of sphere are: <span id="volsphere"></span> </p>
```

JS

```
var radius = document.querySelector("#radius");
var volsphere = document.querySelector("#volsphere");

volsphere.addEventListener("click",function(){
    //calculate the sphere volume
    var spherevolume = (4/3)  * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,3);
    //put the text content into sphere volume
    volsphere.textContent = spherevolume ;
});
```

I try working it out by troubleshooting the console log radius.value and spherevolume.value.

Radius appeared to be fine and giving me "3" but sphere volume have this error message of

> VM97:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: spherevolume is not defined
>       at :1:1

So, which part of the code is giving out this error ?
Thank you to those who helps

Comment: You've got the click listener on the <span>, you should put it on the button. You're not clicking the span, are you?

Comment: Your markup looks invalid`<button id=>Calculate !</button>`
You should fill in a value for the button's id attribute or remove the attribute altogether.

Comment: @Megg My mistake. I should put listener event on the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are multiplying the `HTMLElement` it self and not its value. So add `.value` after radius, like so:

```
var spherevolume = (4/3)  * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius.value, 3);
```

Unfortunately this will return a string and not a number, so to convert it to a number, you could either wrap it in a `parseInt()` or force it to turn into a number (i.e. subtracting it by 0).

```
var spherevolume = (4/3)  * Math.PI * Math.pow(parseInt(radius.value), 3);
```

Or

```
var spherevolume = (4/3)  * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius.value - 0, 3);
```

On a side-note, you should probably add the `EventListener` on the `button` and not on the `span`. I'm assuming you did not do that because the whole thing is in a form and thus it was redirecting the page. You can avoid that by adding a `event.preventDefault();`

```
var button = document.querySelector("#radius+button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var spherevolume = (4/3)  * Math.PI * Math.pow(parseInt(radius.value), 3);
    volsphere.textContent = spherevolume;
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be worth extracting the value into a variable and doing a `parseInt()` on it?